# Javascript code syntax incorrect, not a string

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

How do I change the code syntax below, where is says infoAddress from a number into a string value? What syntax am I missing.

```
var html  = '<a onclick="selectMarker(' + i + '); selectAddress(' + infoAddress + ');">';
```

Comment: What are `i` and `infoAddress`?

Comment: Do not build HTML in JavaScript. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @minitech why is building HTML in JavaScript bad?

Comment: and what do you mean a number to a string value? You are already outputting its value with what you are doing. You can mean make a 5 output as five can you? :O

Comment: @user2782160: Because it is usually to put into `innerHTML`, which is almost always wrong. Use the DOM.

Comment: @minitech: That's fine probably. But don't build JS code strings in JavaScript!

Comment: @user2782160, please ignore my stupidity in the comments to Michael's answer below... he has given you what I believe is the solution - and if you also believe it to be the solution, please make sure you mark his answer as "correct" to let the community know your problem has been solved.

Comment: @Bergi: It is not fine, because stuff like this happens.

Answer (score 3):

If I get your question right, you're trying to give the parameter for the `selectAddress` function as a string. For the parameter must be in quotes. As you're already in a string, you've got to escape the single quotes with a backslash.

```
var html  = '<a onclick="selectMarker(' + i + '); selectAddress(\'' + infoAddress + '\');">linkText</a>';
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question. Here's a little fiddle with what I think the OP is trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/EsmgT/. If that's not it, I'm happy to delete my answer again.

Comment: @Michael, you have not just misunderstood the question, but you appear to have a misunderstanding of javascript syntax... what you have written is simply invalid code. (Edit: and your JSFiddle doesn't even produce a link)

Comment: @freefaller: Maybe you didn’t understand where he meant to put it? `var html  = '<a onclick="selectMarker(' + i + '); selectAddress(\'' + infoAddress + '\');">';`

Comment: @minitech, you're correct - my apologies Michael... it wasn't at all obvious, and I'm having a bad day... I retract my objections (although the fiddle still doesnt' work)

Comment: No problem :) That's because I didn't write a selectMarker & selectAddress function, I just focused on the very problem with the string param.

Comment: Argh... told you I was having a bad day :-(  Thanks @minitech.  Michael can you edit your answer, which will allow me to remove my downvote (my downvote is locked in unless you edit your answer)

Comment: Thank you. But I still can't really tell if this is actually what the OP asked for.

Comment: After all that, I think you're spot on :-)